# Can we find an $f$ so that the mapping cylinder $Mf$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^3 $?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I recently meet with a problem that to determine the mapping cylinder $Mf$, where $f$ is a continuous linear map from $\mathbb{T}^2 $ to $\mathbb{T}^2 $, so that $Mf$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^3 $. I doubt if it is right. How to determine such a continuous map $f$?

Comment: You want to find such an $f$?

Comment: Yes, such an $f$ is a linear transform between $\mathbb{R}^2 $ descending to $\mathbb{T}^2 $.

Comment: can you figure out the homeomorphism type for $f$ the identity? or a constant? Also your title question is different from your question.

Comment: Any mapping cylinder of a map from a space to itself is homotopy equivalent to that space. So you are right this is impossible.

Comment: It is my fault. I apologize.@AndresMejia

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this hasn't been answered: no. One can check that a mapping cylinder for a map $f:X  \to Y$ is homotopy equivalent to $Y$, by retracting $X$ to $f(X)$ via $I$. In particular

$M_f$  cannot be homeomorphic to $S^3$ since they are not even homotopic (which can be seen by checking fundamental groups of $T^2$ and $S^3$.